# 16.10 Obiaf's driver not showing at additional drivers

Tags: drivers, unity, amd-graphics, 16.10

I just installed mesa packages and obiaf's amd driver from ppa. (I'm using R9 280)

I want to enable hardware acceleration for unity desktop because it has ugly and slow rendering.

But at the additional drivers window obiaf's driver is not showing at the Additional Drivers window.

[Additional Drivers Window Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz9FE.png)

Thanks!

Comment: If you installed them, they should be in use. I don't think the Additional Drivers app supports/recognizes the Oibaf drivers. All the app is doing anyway is installing the chosen driver. Ubuntu uses it automatically.

Comment: But there is no speed up after that.
http://imgur.com/ctjj1qQ Why is still slow?

Comment: There's no guarantee they'll actually work. You'll just have to downgrade to 14.04. wait, or get NVIDIA.